# Disable emulation of middle click via simultaneous left and right click

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I am using MATE Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I clumsily keep accidentally simulating the middle click by simultaneously clicking the left and right click, I really want to disable it, I can not see the option in the touchpad settings. Please help.

Comment: Do you remember the way you used to set this option? Is it was set from GUI or from terminal?

Comment: I never set it. It was set by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use gsettings or dconf-editor to disable this function..

to get the value, use

```
gsettings get org.mate.peripherals-mouse middle-button-enabled
```

to set the value to false, use

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse middle-button-enabled false
```

Dconf-Editor (If not installed, `sudo apt install dconf-editor`)

[image]